# Is there a way to create lists of TBDs and TBCs in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I need to create a list or table of TBD (To Be Defined) and TBC (To Be Confirmed) items in Microsoft Word. Usage would be as follows:

In some part of the document I will write something like:

> The data rate for the link between A and B is TBD1.
>
> ...
>
> The link occupancy rate between A and B is 90% TBC1.
>
> ...
>
> The MTU for the same link is 1500 bytes TBC2.

Later, I want to be able to build a table where I can have:

```
| Item ID | Description                       |
| TBD1    | What needs to be defined for TBD1 |
| TBDn    | What needs to be defined for TBDn |
```

and

```
| Item ID | Description                         |
| TBC1    | What needs to be confirmed for TBC1 |
| TBCn    | What needs to be confirmed for TBCn |
```

I'm happy if I can just have some way to manually tag TBCs and TBDs, and that I can insert manually the references in the tables, but so that the back reference is kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for a purely manual approach, you could use bookmarks.

Select, e.g., the text 'TBD1', and then add a bookmark. (On the **Insert** tab, click **Bookmark**, and enter a name; **TBD1** is a good choice.)

Then to create the entries in the Item ID column of your table, you can insert a cross-reference to the bookmark. (On the **Insert** tab, click **Cross-reference**, select **Bookmark** in the **Reference type** field and **Bookmark text** in the **Insert reference to** field, either select or clear the **Insert as hyperlink** check box, and then select the bookmark.) The exact text that you selected when you added the bookmark will be inserted.

Or, if you want the reference to look like a clickable link, you can insert a hyperlink. (On the **Insert** tab, click **Hyperlink**, click **Place in This Document**, and then select the bookmark.) The caveat here is that this approach inserts the exact *name* of the bookmark, not the *text* of it; however, if you make those 2 values identical (e.g., 'TBD1'), as you can easily get away with for your scenario, it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried the bookmark route, but I did it without the selection step, and did not work (as the content was empty, I now realize). I'll use that for this document, I will wait for a more automatic approach for the next… if anything comes up!

Answer (score 1):

Create or use TBD Caption stile for your captions:

Then::
Use styles to create a table of figures

```
Click where you want to insert the table of figures.
On the References tab, in the Captions group, click Insert Table of Figures.
Click Options.
Select the Style check box.
In the Style list, click the style that you applied to the captions, and then click OK.
```

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-table-of-figures-c5ea59c5-487c-4fb2-bd48-e34dd57f0ec1